# R equivalent of Python df.to_dict(orient="list")

Tags: python, r, json

I'm trying to convert and R tibble in a Shiny app to a JSON. I can use `jsonlite::toJSON()` to do this, but unfortunately the recipient requires the output in a different order. I've tried converting the input from long to wide, but this comes out all wrong.

The Python code to create the JSON uses

```py
df.to_dict(orient="list")
```

I need an R equivalent of this.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

#Sample tibbble
tibble <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = letters[1:3], col3 = c("x", "y", "z"))

#You can change the order with this
# tibble_reordered <- tibble %>% select(desired_order)

#Convert tibble to list of named vectors
tibble_list <- as.list(tibble) #Use tibble_reordered if you reordered it
tibble_list <- lapply(tibble_list, as.vector)
names(tibble_list) <- names(tibble)  # Set column names as keys

#Convert list to JSON
json_output <- toJSON(tibble_list, auto = FALSE)

cat(json_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Æsad has the right end goal, then [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rjsoncons) package [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons)

```
rjsoncons::j_pivot(tibble)
```

gets you there, too.

```
> j_pivot(tibble) |> noquote()
[1] {"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":["a","b","c"],"col3":["x","y","z"]}
```

I believe that another solution is just `toJSON(unclass(tibble))`